# Can you change difficulty on Spartan Ops Multiplayer

Tags: halo-4

Can you change the difficulty on matchmaker Spartan Ops missions?  There are some challenges to complete the missions on Legendary, and I didn't see any place where I could search for matches with higher difficulty.

Do I have to stick to solo mode or playing with friends to play Spartan Ops on Legendary?

Comment: It doesn't look that way, but I can't rule it out completely yet.  Reach had a mode where you voted for the difficulty after you were in a lobby, but I don't have time to play through an entire match right now, and I'd hate to quit early and leave people hanging :(

Comment: Good question - this is damn frustrating. For me match-made ops games are always heroic, but I want to match-make exclusively on legendary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In public multiplayer, based on the experience I've had so far - the first 3 seem to be Legendary difficulty and the last 2 Heroic. Every time I play I get this same structure.

The only way to select difficulty is to start a private Spartan Ops match and you can choose the difficulty, but it doesn't appear to me that you can make it public, so you either have to go it alone (Might suit some, but I don't fancy it!) or have enough available friends.

Quite a few achievements in this game are frustrating to get because the game leans you away from the goal!

Comment: With episode 2, all 5 chapters are locked to Heroic in public multiplayer, curious!

Answer (score 1):

If you start a new Spartan Ops chapter it looks like there's a difficulty selector. Other than that there doesn't seem to be a way to choose.

Comment: This is for friend matches only. You can't match-make from here.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't change it, every time i matchmake i find 3 people so with 4 of us it defaults to legendary, did you try with 4 ppl or was it less? I know once i played and found only 1 guy and it was on normal.

I have to assume it's based on the number of players

Comment: I had 4 every time.  Maybe it looks a player ranking as well.

Comment: For me it's always heroic, whether 4 players or 2.