# How can I choose which chapter to play in Spartan Ops?

Tags: halo-4

I have completed chapter one with friends in a private match and I just finished playing chapter 2 online, but there does not seem to be an option to choose which chapter to play when online matchmaking.

I want to play chapter one online so I can get it on legendary and after that I want to go to chapter 3 but I only have the option to play chapter 2 online.

Can somebody tell me how I can choose or is there no option to choose?

Comment: Related, but not a dupe of: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/92466/can-you-change-difficulty-on-spartan-ops-multiplayer

Answer (score 4):

In "matchmaking" Spartan Ops (where you play with your Halo 4 party or with random strangers) the available ops and their difficulty is set by Microsoft/343 Industries and you may only select from ones that they have chosen for you.  The current rotation appears to change weekly.  To date, this has always been the "op released this week" when ops are being released, and it has varied in the off season.  (One week it was a grab bag, but now it seems to be one Episode per week, on Legendary)

In "private game" Spartan Ops (where you can either play solo or with a party of up to 4 friends), you can choose from any of the unlocked ops, and you can pick the difficulty level.

Answer (score 0):

In "matchmaking" Spartan Ops (where you play with your Halo 4 party or with random strangers) the available ops and their difficulty is set by Microsoft/343 Industries and you may only select from ones that they have chosen for you. The current rotation appears to change weekly. To date, this has always been the "op released this week" when ops are being released, and it has varied in the off season. (One week it was a grab bag, but now it seems to be one Episode per week, on Legendary)
In "matchmaking" Spartan Ops (where you play with your Halo 4 party or with random strangers) the available ops and their difficulty is set by Microsoft/343 Industries and you may only select from ones that they have chosen for you. The current rotation appears to change weekly. To date, this has always been the "op released this week" when ops are being released, and it has varied in the off season. (One week it was a grab bag, but now it seems to be one Episode per week, on Legendary)